# Connection Kit Basics

Tags: cocoa, frameworks

I need to implement file transfer in my application and it seems that in Cocoa [ConnectionKit](https://github.com/karelia/ConnectionK) is unofficial standard. I was able to compile it but I have struggled finding any documentation or examples of it's use. The only [example](http://www.matthew-long.com/2007/11/24/cocoaobjective-c-ftp-libraryframework/) I found was outdated and even with modification I could not get it to work. Does anyone know the basic functions (creating connections, uploading...).

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Its pretty simple once you figure out how its laid out.

Heres the code to create an ftp connection

```
CKConnectionRequest *request = [CKConnectionRequest requestWithURL:url];
CKFTPConnection *ftpConn = [[CKFTPConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request];
[ftpConn setDelegate:self];
[ftpConn connect];
self.connection = ftpConn;
[ftpConn release];
```

Then you would interact with the Connection Delegate methods found in CKConnectionProtocol.h
To authenticate to the server above you would use this delegate method where "cred" is an instance of NSURLCredential you have set up with the credentials you need.

```
- (void)connection:(id <CKConnection>)connection 
didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:cred forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}
```

For an upload you would just call one of the upload methods specified in CKConnectionProtocol.h inside of a delegate method like below

```
- (void)connection:(id <CKConnection>)con
didOpenAtPath:(NSString *)dirPath error:(NSError *)error {
   CKTransferRecord *tr = [con uploadLocalItem:localPath
                             toRemoteDirectory:remotePath
                             ignoreHiddenItems:YES];
}
```

Then you would receive callbacks as to the status of that upload via the Uploading Methods specified in CKConnectionProtocol.h

Hopefully that helps. Forgive any small errors in the code I typed it out not copy/paste

Comment: Thanks for the code, I couldn't find any examples anywhere. I don't have time to try it how, but I will soon.